# XML Response sent from django is null in the javascript

Tags: ajax, django, dojo

I am using dojo for django in my project. I am calling url from the dojo.xhrPost method. Here is the code snippet

```
dojo.xhrPost( {
form: cvForm,
url: '/config/validate_cfgtask/',
handleAs: "xml",
timeout: 0, // in millisec
// The LOAD function will be called on a successful response.
load: function(response, ioArgs) {
    console.log('debug response : '+response+"status "+ioArgs.xhr.status);
     }
     });
```

I have included the entried for this url in urls.py file

Here is the code that process this request
def validate_cfgtasknew(request, taskid):
    xml         = ""
    status = 'true'
    resultmsg= 'No validation error is found.'
    sshtaskid = 69
    xml+="""
    %s
    %s
    %s
    """ % (status, resultmsg, str(sshtaskid))
    xml+=""
    xml = xmltemplate % (valid, xml)
    return HttpResponse(xml, mimetype="text/xml")

When i print the value of xml in python it is

```
   <result><sshtask>
    <status>true</status>
    <message>No validation error is found.</message>
    <taskid>69</taskid>
    </sshtask></result>
   </response>
```

The problem is when i print the xml in the python code i get the proper xml data as given above. but the value of the response in the load method of dojo is null.

DEBUG got response null status : 200

When i run this in my windows machine it is working fine. This seems to be a simple issue. I am missing something very simple. Help on resolving this issue is required.

Comment: Not enough information here. What is the rest of the `xml` variable? What is `xmltemplate`? Is the combination of all that actually valid XML? What is the actual output of the `console.log` call?

Comment: So many things wrong with this code, I don't even know where to start

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue resolved.

Previously i didn't access or use the request object that is being passed to the Django view. Instead i used the query parameter and did the processing. When i just access the request object once i am able to get the proper response in the javascript.

```
def validate_cfgtasknew(request, taskid):
xml = ""
status = 'true'
resultmsg= 'No validation error is found.'
sshtaskid = 69
querydict = request.POST
xml = <result><sshtask>
<status>true</status>
<message>No validation error is found.</message>
<taskid>69</taskid>
</sshtask></result>
```

return HttpResponse(xml, mimetype="text/xml")

```
querydict = request.POST
```

is the line that i have added to get the xml document object back in my javascript.

however i dont understand this behaviour. If any explanation is there it will be helpful.